# LEGO LOTR Achievement Icon "... And away he goes, Precious!"

Tags: achievements, lego-lord-of-the-rings

Can anyone tell me what this icon is actually showing? It's for the following achievement http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/lego-lord-of-the-rings/achievement/73761-----And-away-he-goes--Precious-.html

Original:

[image: Lego Icon]

I've highlighted what I think are eyes and I'm guessing is the Ring, but apart from that I can't work it out. It looks kind of like Squirtle.

[image: Lego Icon annotated]

Answer (score 7):

[image: ZoomTimes4]

Here's the image blown up.  Looks like Gollum.

Answer (score 4):

Gollum.  He is holding the ring in his left hand, looking up to his right (your left).